# Tab-Tab snippet expansion doesn't work in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms, code-snippets, ssms-2012

In Visual Studio, you can invoke a snippet by typing its shortcut followed by <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>. For example, typing `prop`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> gives you this:

[image: Screenshot]

In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), this doesn't seem to work. (I'm using SSMS 2012.)

In both environments you can type <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> and then navigate through folders of snippets, but I find this far more clumsy.

Is there a way to make *shortcut* <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> work in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: didnt even know it existed, Once you start typing it shows you a drop down of available option One Tab completes the word for you but not the whole code snippet like we can do in Visual Studio.

Comment: @marc_s I'm using 2012. I've updated the question & tags to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party tool that will provide this functionality, for example the great SSMS Tools Pack, or SQL Prompt, or SQL Complete.

Comment: And SSMSBoost has this functionality as well. (I am developer of SSMSBoost)

Comment: SSMSBoost requires you to use its "auto replacement templates", rather than the snippets that you (may) have already defined (Tools | Code Snippets Manager...).  This is less than satisfactory.